# how to transfer a directory from a macbook using rsync to a windows wsl ubuntu directory

Tags: windows, unix

I have an updated copy of my home directory on my Macbook that I would like to replicate in my Windows 11 WSL Ubuntu machine (in its ext4 file system).  I would like to use rsync to do so, if possible.  I definitely do not want to go through the Windows file system as there are symbolic links I want preserved. I'd also like to do it from the WSL side if possible, as the directory is stored in some vhd format in Windows, but when I have the WSL Ubuntu open, it sees it as an ext4 file system.

From what I read in the rsync man pages suggest I need an ssh connection to the mac, not an smb connection.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you attempted in using [Rsync over SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83690/107777)?  What results did you get?

Answer (score 1):

I found the directions to setup ssh on my macbook.  It's SystemPreferences Sharing RemoteLogin.

Once, I enabled that I was able in my WSL Ubuntu invoke rsync using ssh.

```
rsync -avz myname@192.168.100.54:/Users/myname /home/myname
```

where myname is my username and 192.168.100.54 is the IP address that showed up in the SystemPreferences Sharing RemoteLogin widget on the Mac.

It did ask a couple of questions, e.g. did I recognize the machine it was connecting to and the password for my mac, but otherwise it was relatively straight-forward once I found out how to tell my mac to accept ssh connections (and to add the ssh address to the rsync command).